# Print jobs sent to server OK, but then get deleted

Tags: shared-printers

I have 2 HP computers, one running Win XP SP3, one running Win7. I have a Lexmark X4270 All-in-One printer attached to the Win7 machine via a USB port. I can print OK from the Win 7 machine, but when I print from the WinXP machine, the print job shows up in both print queues (showing the same number of bytes - which is good!), but then the status gets changed to "Deleting - Sent to printer", and that status shows up in both print queues.   The print job then stays there until I do a cancel, followed by a system restart.

FWIW the owner is shown as Guest, but I have permission for Everyone set to print...

I believe I have up-to-date drivers; I don't believe it's a firewall problem.  What I would like to see is the Win7 machine's reason for deleting my print jobs - is there a diagnostic tool available?

Also, I notice that the port for this printer on the WinXP machine is set to USB001 - I would have thought something like \servername\sharedprinter would be more appropriate - and I can see that in the list of ports, but the system doesn't let me change the port name from USB001...

Could someone shed some light?  I have spent *hours* on this! TIA

BTW I can do file sharing, no problem!

Answer (score 1):

I would use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to capture the stack when the print job is run.  It may capture what is causing it to cancel printing.  Also, are there any errors in the application or system event viewer (on either machine)?  Print job errors will sometimes be logged here.

The fact that the port is USB001 on the XP machine is ok.  It's noting the port that the printer is accepting commands on.  For example, for a network printer attached via ethernet, the port number would be the IP address, even though the share name for the printer is \\server\sharedprinter.

Comment: Thanks, Holocryptic - I hadn't heard of the Process Monitor - I'll give both tools a try.   Thanks also for clarifying the USB001 indication.

Comment: Process Monitor doesn't pick up anything, and event logs don't show any error - any other tools or logs?

Comment: @Paul what architecture are the two computers running?

Comment: Hi @Holocryptic, After trying for several days, I gave in and bought a new printer, which has a wireless option.  It is attached via USB to the old XP machine, and that works.  Installing on the Win7 machine should be much simpler, as only one machine is involved, but the installation procedure seems to think there is a firewall that I don't know about :-)  How do I find an invisible firewall?!  Try install in safe mode?  Probably silly question...

Comment: Had another thought: the Win7 machine and the printer are both talking wirelessly to the Linksys - could this be the problem?  If so, what needs to be changed?  TIA

Comment: Hold everything - the support guy at Brother figured out a possible solution - I'm going to try it now!  Thanks anyway!

Comment: Yup, that was the problem - the new machine is now working!  Sorry to have wasted people's time with my first question - I didn't realize how much printers have changed over the years!  Still, I learned a lot!  Thanks, @Holocryptic!